# How to query all IDs by a value from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase

Here is my data on Firebase

```
  {
  "messages" : {
    "-KFdphRHtKSovYfCRYWE" : {
      "senderId" : "95cf99d8-377b-4685-a8ee-2afe69a82419",
      "text" : "Chechen"
    },
    "-KFdpisBYxFaSrm2CO67" : {
      "senderId" : "425c9449-b3f7-4d21-b57c-4134b76712dd",
      "text" : "sdd"
    },
    "-KFdpmKXuRrzDnl_JRmF" : {
      "senderId" : "425c9449-b3f7-4d21-b57c-4134b76712dd",
      "text" : "c dđcv"
    },
    "-KFdpnSJIX48yh1KpjFo" : {
      "senderId" : "95cf99d8-377b-4685-a8ee-2afe69a82419",
      "text" : "Bilbo,m"
    }
  },
  "tasks" : {
    "-KEPuc8aGpYLT0-NOo50" : {
      "assignee" : "Kaito Kid",
      "description" : "Task1",
      "endTime" : "13:58 Thursday,07/04",
      "from" : "Khuong Pham",
      "priority" : 1,
      "progress" : 10,
      "startTime" : "13:58 Tuesday,05/04"
    },
    "-KFbsI0Q6WB5dWc90pIR" : {
      "assignee" : "Khoa Pham",
      "description" : "Task2",
      "endTime" : "12:38 Thursday,21/04",
      "from" : "Khuong Pham",
      "priority" : 2,
      "progress" : 0,
      "startTime" : "12:38 Wednesday,20/04"
    },
    "-KFdngdnHyfG2pygRx3L" : {
      "assignee" : "Khoa Pham",
      "description" : "Task3",
      "endTime" : "21:37 Wednesday,20/04",
      "from" : "Khuong Pham",
      "priority" : 0,
      "progress" : 10,
      "startTime" : "21:37 Tuesday,19/04"
    },
    "-KFdo-Q8HrrPZoaQcGRj" : {
      "assignee" : "Khuong Pham",
      "description" : "task4",
      "endTime" : "23:44 Thứ Hai,18/04",
      "from" : "Khoa Pham",
      "priority" : 1,
      "progress" : 7,
      "startTime" : "21:41 Thứ Hai,18/04"
    },
    "-KFdpXmuGrLOBonb976Q" : {
      "assignee" : "Khoa Pham",
      "description" : "Task5",
      "endTime" : "21:46 Friday,22/04",
      "from" : "Khuong Pham",
      "priority" : 2,
      "progress" : 0,
      "startTime" : "21:46 Tuesday,19/04"
    },
    "-KFdpdnPb_BVIDQ32Ym6" : {
      "assignee" : "Khuong Pham",
      "description" : "task6",
      "endTime" : "23:46 Thứ Hai,18/04",
      "from" : "Khoa Pham",
      "priority" : 1,
      "progress" : 0,
      "startTime" : "23:46 Thứ Hai,18/04"
    }
  },
  "typingIndicator" : {
    "95cf99d8-377b-4685-a8ee-2afe69a82419" : false
  },
  "users" : {
    "33ab67aa-6357-4f3e-aee8-623e294c7de2" : {
      "dateJoin" : "19/04/2016",
      "dateOfBirth" : "01/01/1990",
      "firstName" : "Binh",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "group" : "PHP ",
      "lastName" : "Nguyen",
      "phone" : "0123456789",
      "position" : "PHP Developer"
    },
    "425c9449-b3f7-4d21-b57c-4134b76712dd" : {
      "dateJoin" : "01/01/2010",
      "dateOfBirth" : "03/03/1990",
      "firstName" : "Khoa",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "group" : "iOS Team",
      "lastName" : "Pham",
      "phone" : "0939133994",
      "position" : "Senior iOS Developer"
    },
    "95cf99d8-377b-4685-a8ee-2afe69a82419" : {
      "dateJoin" : "20/01/2016",
      "dateOfBirth" : "29/10/1993",
      "firstName" : "Khuong",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "group" : "iOS Team",
      "lastName" : "Pham",
      "phone" : "01655961231",
      "position" : "iOS Developer"
    },
    "f88a6c6f-cbc8-4d37-a7d9-4ee4c3a6fd32" : {
      "dateJoin" : "13/03/2016",
      "dateOfBirth" : "01/01/1993",
      "firstName" : "Kaito",
      "gender" : "Male",
      "group" : "Android Team",
      "lastName" : "Kid",
      "phone" : "0939133994",
      "position" : "Android Developer"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to query all IDs which has "from" key that has value "Khuong Pham".

```
FIREBASE_REF.childByAppendingPath("tasks").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in
            print(snapshot.key) // all IDs
            print(snapshot.value)
            // Then Use this value to compare with "from" key has value "Khuong Pham"
            // Then find the ID of it.
        })
```

If I try this way, I have to spend more time to filter them.

Is there anyway to query faster that I can get the ID.

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE**:

Here is the code:

```
func deleteTaskInFireBase() {
      FIREBASE_REF.childByAppendingPath("tasks").queryOrderedByChild("from").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
        if let from = snapshot.value["from"] as? String where (snapshot.value["from"] as? String) == "Khuong Pham" {
            print("\(snapshot.key): \(from)")
        }
    })

}
```

Result is:

```
-KEPuc8aGpYLT0-NOo50: Khuong Pham
-KFbsI0Q6WB5dWc90pIR: Khuong Pham
-KFdngdnHyfG2pygRx3L: Khuong Pham
-KFdpXmuGrLOBonb976Q: Khuong Pham
```

Comment: Aside from that, see https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries

Comment: Edited it to JSON as text.

Comment: Thanks for that (cleaning up comments). Now did you also read the page that I linked to? Because it covers exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: The reason I want to ask this question because I want to delete data at indexPath.row, so I want to query like this, and delete at indexPath with it. But using this case seem not work. Because It just print one by one. My expert function will be deleteTaskInFireBase(index: Int)

Comment: Retrieving all items and then filtering client-side is a certain way to make your users unhappy about bandwidth usage. Read the rest of that page as it explains how to use `queryEqualToValue()` to perform the filtering on the server.

Comment: I store them in the array call IDs, then I use this to delete FIREBASE_REF.childByAppendingPath("tasks").childByAppendingPath(IDs[indexPath.row]).removeValue()

Comment: Thanks a lot @FrankvanPuffelen for your help.